# new wagtail install with gunicorn, nginx, ubuntu 22, not loading images right

Tags: wagtail

can someone look at this and tell me what's wrong? I installed wagtail with nginx and gunicorn on ubuntu, and it is like the images / css not loading ? https://diynft.site/

Thanks in advance.

seems like similar issue to this , but django not wagtail.
[Django Admin not working / ugly - serving with nginx and gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181121/django-admin-not-working-ugly-serving-with-nginx-and-gunicorn)

from the comment, "The proper way to solve this is to add include /etc/nginx/mime.types; in the http section of the nginx configuration file." , I did verify that was included...

Answer (score 0):

Your image files look ok - or should if you fix the problem with serving the welcome_page.css file. That is really a Django-level issue so this article should help you figure out what piece is missing: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-static-files/ Scroll towards the end for info on setting up ngnix to serve your static files.

Answer (score 0):

thanks!! got it working after the above suggestion yielded same results.  it was the nginx site configuration file , followed explicitly per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).